# Arrow keys in iframe affecting my main screen

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I have made a game with JavaScript and PHP and when I put the game inside an iframe everything is normal but once I start pressing the arrow keys (it's a snake game) my main window starts moving too. Go take a quick look at this site so you have a better idea of what I mean.

http://www.dbzweb.be/08/braetj08/

I have tried some things with cancelbubble but that didn't help. Could someone please tell me how to avoid my main frame from moving though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the keypress event to stop it from moving.

```
var cancelKeypress = false;

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    cancelKeypress = /^(37|38|39|40)$/.test("" + evt.keyCode);
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};

/* For Opera */
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: And where are you putting this code? Are you cancelling the keypresses in your game code?